# Controlling R&S signal generator with python

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket
import time

TCP_IP = 'rssmb100a110186.local'
TCP_PORT = 5025


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))

for i in range(0,2):
    s.send(b"outp on")
    print('set output on')
    time.sleep(1)
    s.send(b'outp on')
    print('set output off')
    time.sleep(1)
print('shutdown')

s.send(b'SYST:REB') # reboot generator
```

I need to control a Rohde & Schwarz SMB 100A RF signal generator using python. When using putty to send the commands using "RAW" or TELNET option, everything is ok...

When using my (test) python script, the generator switches to "remote operation mode" and in the web gui of this device, I can see that the SCPI commands are received, but nothing happens. When I replace the socket with the telnetlib same problem. I also have no errors when executing my python script.

What's the difference between my python script and putty?

Comment: _"What's the difference between my python script and putty?"_ -- add the telnet part of the equation into the question, too, for us to be able to say.

Comment: You can use a sniffer to compare the raw network packets -- that will tell you the difference for sure.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add newlines -- otherwise, the device has no way to determine if the command is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan Pozdeev wrote in the comments on the Original question, the newline character \n is important!

doesn't switch the output on:

```
s.send(b"outp on")
```

solution: add \n:

```
s.send(b"outp on\n")
```